# Replacing nothing with a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

This may be a simple question, but I have searched quite a few sites and have tried a few of my own ideas and I still cannot seem to find a simple way to get Visual Studio to replace all of the listbox items with the string of nothing with some other text.

Using things such as :

```
For Each S In ListBox1.Items
            S.Replace("", "Not Blank")
        Next
```

Shows:

> Error
>   String cannot be of zero length

Which is quite annoying because the actual listbox item contains no text.
This seems to be one of the easiest things I have ever encountered while using vb.net. But it now seems very hard for what should be a simple command.

Comment: use `Option Strict On`. you will immediately see an issue with `S.Replace("", "Not Blank")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems.  The Replace function *returns* a new value, and you promptly ignore it.  Second, you can't really modify the collection as you For-Each over it, so a For-Loop would be more appropriate.

I think you want something like this instead:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString) Then
    ListBox1.Items(i) = "Not Blank"
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing that out. I would have been here for hours trying so many different things. (It works perfectly!)

Comment: You could also look at `IsNullOrWhitespace`.